# Prove that either $Ax=b$ for all $b$ or $A^*y=0$ has a non zero solution

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

Given an operator $A$ in hermtian space.

Prove that either $Ax=b$ for all $b$ or $A^*y=0$ has a non-zero solution.

I tried to assume that there exist such $b$ for which there is no solution.
Then I tried to use a property of adjoint operator, namely $<A^*y, b> = <y, Ab>$, but I don' t what to say further.

I think I should somehow conclude that right side is non-zero and it will imply that there exist a non-zero solution for $A^*y =0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need $A$ to be Hermitian.

If $A$ is invertible, then $Ax=b$ has solution for all $b$ (and the solution will be nonzero whenever $b\ne0$.

If $A$ is not invertible, then neither is $A^*$, and so $A^*y=0$ has a nonzero solution.

Comment: Sorry, for asking dumb questions, but can you please explain why $A^*$ is invertible and why $A^*y = 0$ has a non-zero solution? For the first, I think it is just follows from the definition, because we are using $Ax$ everywhere.

Comment: You have $det A^*=\overline{\det A}$. And, for the second question, a matrix is invertible if and only if its kernel is nontrivial.

Comment: Thanks! And this sentence only exist due to Math SE restriction.

Comment: You are welcome. And you can simply use a blank math expression, like spaces (backslash-space).